# Android Realm.io - Removing sub-objects

Tags: android, realm

Let's say I have a structure of realm-objects that looks like this -

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {

   @PrimaryKey
   private int id;

   private String name;

   private List<Pet> pets

   // Setters, getters...
}

public class Pet extends RealmObject {

    private String name;

    private MedicalRecord record;

    // Setters, getters...

}

public class MedicalRecord extends RealmObject {

    private String something;

    private String somethingElse;

    // Setters, getters...

}
```

Now I received a new Person object with an existing id (primary-key) and I want to update this person.
So I do something like this -

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(person);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

The trouble is that this person's pet list (and the pets' medical records), are still out there in the db. not linked anymore to this person, but still there.

I tried to do this -

```
Person existingPerson = realm.where(Person .class).equalTo("id", ID).findFirst();
existingPerson.getPets().clear();
```

But no success there. How can I remove subobjects of realmObjects?

Also, is there a way to define a policy for a realm-object so that it will remove itself once there is no reference to it (it's not linked to any parent-object)?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you question before. There is no method to clear and delete all objects from  `RealmList` for now, see this issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1560 and https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1104 . Currently the workaround is delete every object in a loop with a reverse order like this: 
    for (int i = dogs.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        dogs.get(i).removeFromRealm();
    }

Comment: `RealmList.removeFromRealm()` will be merged soon, you can see the progress in this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2061

Comment: `RealmList.removeFromRealm()` has been merged to the master, you can wait for the next release or try it with snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can, and method was renamed from last commit to `realmList.deleteAllFromRealm()`